# Calculating mean values on a complicated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter

Im trying to figure out how to calculate the average cost of employees per country. I have tried using the mean() function, but the line of code is not complicated enough to pull out the average cost of employees per country. Do you guys have any tips for how to get it done? Is it to complicated as it stands right now, and do i need to do it step by step by using for an example, groupby?

Feel free to ask for more information surrounding this problem. I hope i have showcased enough for you to understand the problem and help me with a soloution.

[Picture of the current csv file im working on, there has been some cleaning done to it. There are several countries inside this dataframe, not just the ones you see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djpEM.png)

[Here so you can see what other country is inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqNNI.png)

Comment: you can use pandas `groupby(country)['Employees].mean()`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html

Comment: I got this error. NameError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-265fc76e668a> in <module>
----> 1 Denmark_Costs = Employee_Costs.groupby(Denmark)['Employees'].mean()

NameError: name 'Denmark' is not defined .

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass *Denmark* (variable name), instead of "Denmark" (string, in quotes). The NameError is due to the fact that you haven't previously defined a variable *Denmark*.

Comment: Please post your code in the question so we can help you better